# Create a list without ngRepeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I would like to create a directive, that does not need ngRepeat, because there is some additional functionality on the directive, that doesn't play good with ngRrepeat.

This is my directive with ng-repeat:

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in items track by $index" ng-class="attrs.itemTheme" data-item="{{ item[attrs.itemId]}}">
        <div ng-include="attrs.tpl"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

attrs.tpl, nt-dimension is another directive, that uses the items values from ngRepeat:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="dimension-item-tpl.html">
    <div nt-dimension x-attrs="item"></div>
</script>
```

Without ngRepeat:

```
<div> 
   <ul></ul>
</div>
```

Can some please give me an example, I am quit struggling with this.

Example of code:
http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/4zhLtjbw/

Not working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/ztLhpf2g/

Got to compile and append the ngIncluded template, but the problem is, that it compiles only the last one, because the digest cycle is to slow.

```
var el = jqElm.find('ul');
scope.attrs.list.forEach(function (vl) {
    var tmp = 
        '<li class="' + attrs.itemTheme + '" data-item="' + vl.id + '">' +
            '<div ng-include="\'' + attrs.itemTpl + '\'"></div>' +
                '</li>';

    scope.item = vl; // this is to slow :(

    var b = $compile(tmp)(scope);
    el.append(b);
});
```

Comment: Take a look at this post

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269184/how-to-insert-compiled-html-code-inside-the-directive-without-getting-digest

Comment: Error: [$interpolate:interr] Can't interpolate: 
        {{ generatedList }}

Comment: and how would this work, here I would still need ngRepeat

Comment: ok, got to compile the list, but now I have a problem with the usage of ng-include, how to pass item here???

Comment: really, no one wanted to do this before me?????

Comment: need to sleep occasionally

Comment: any suggestions? i really need this.

Comment: There's not even angular in the fiddle, how are we supposed to detect where it goes wrong? It's better to have a minimal example that fails exactly like you describe than only some parts of code.

Comment: created a jsfiddle, not working example: http://jsfiddle.net/mato75/ztLhpf2g/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to manually create an own scope for each `li`, so each item has its own data.

```
var ul = jqElm.find('ul');

scope.list.forEach(function (vl) {
var li = '<li><div ng-include="\'item-tpl2.html\'"></div></li>';
var newScope = scope.$new();
newScope.item = vl;
var cLi = $compile(li)(newScope);
ul.append(cLi);
```

Comment: thank you, that is really awesome. thx, if I ever meet you, first round is on me